# Meteor Subscribe and Publish not returning data

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following pub in my Meteor app and sub in my iron router, however for the data function I'm not getting anything back, if I change my publish to topics and not public topics then it's fine. But that can't be correct as then have the same publish twice and I get a meteor message about it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I would like to have a set of public topics based on the url

```
Meteor.publish('topics' , function() {
    return Topics.find({$or:[{userId: this.userId},{collaboratorsIds: this.userId},{inviteeId:this.userId}]});
});


Meteor.publish('publicTopics' , function(permalinkUser,permalink) {
    return Topics.find({$and:[{permalinkUser: this.permalinkUser},{permalink: this.permalink}]});
});
```

and in my iron-router I have the following

```
this.route('topicPublic', {
        path: 'public/:permalinkUser/:permalink',
        layoutTemplate: 'layoutApp',
        waitOn: function(){
            return [Meteor.subscribe('publicTopics', this.params.permalinkUser,this.params.permalink)]
        },


        data: function(){
            return Topics.findOne({$and:[{permalinkUser: this.params.permalinkUser},{permalink: this.params.permalink}]});

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your publicTopics publish function is wrong. If you pass a parameter to a function you don't use this.permalinkUser inside function but just permalinkUser. Learn more about functions on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

```
Meteor.publish('publicTopics' , function(permalinkUser,permalink) {
  return Topics.find({$and:[{permalinkUser: permalinkUser},{permalink: permalink}]});
});
```

In your topics publish function you use this.userId because it's property of Meteor object.

Comment: Yes my mistake wasn't paying attention I copied the return from the router data function.

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove "this" -- my mistake wasn't paying attention I copied the return from the router data function.